# Como mostrar códigos-fonte em telas como sites de ajuda?

Tags: php

Como fazer para cadastrar e mostrar códigos-fontes em tela como neste site?

Estou criando um site onde cadastro tudo o que desenvolvo como biblioteca.
Mas quero que mostre na tela os códigos quando eu escolher um artigo.
Tentei cadastrar como se fosse texto e dar echo em tela, mas ele executa dentro do banco de dados.

Answer (score 3):

Para escapar o código fonte php e dar um highlight, use a função [highlight_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php), para guardar o retorno em uma variável passe `true` como segundo argumento.

```
<?php
$str = '<?php 
            $n1 = 10;
            $n2 = 5;
            echo $n1 + $n2;';

//Exibe o valor na tela 
highlight_string($str);

//Não exibe na tela
$code = highlight_string($str, true);
```

[Exemplo - phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d7fp-0bfa)